# Able to SSH localhost, but other computers can't be hosted on it

Tags: windows-10, ssh, hosts

I am trying to get access to a certain computer (A) via SSH, but I am unable to.
On the "certain computer" (A) I am able to SSH localhost itself, but other 
computers cannot use the SSH (IP) to connect to the computer.
Do you have any idea(s), of the cause of this problem ?

The host is on Windows 10

Comment: What is the error you receive? Are the other hosts on the same network as A? Are there any firewalls in between? Have you opened up the fw rules on the host to allow ssh from remote sources?

Comment: Alright, the problem source was the firewall